# passing char buf[] to function parameter unsigned char * value

Tags: visual-c++

I have function:

```
string f1 (unsigned char * value, int len)
{
...
}
```

I would like to pass to it variable that is

```
char buf[4096];
```

What is the best method to do this?

Comment: "What is the best method to do this?" How do you define "best method"? For the cast, there's a short version (see icepack -> C-style), a clear version (`reinterpret_cast`) and many more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess `len` refers to the number of elements in the buffer (better look it up in the documentation of `f1`). You can get that with:

```
sizeof(buf) // as `sizeof(char)==1`
// or
sizeof(buf)/sizeof(buf[0])  // more commonly used, works with all types
```

This works here as `sizeof(char) == sizeof(unsigned char) == 1`.

The other point is that you cannot call

```
f1(buf, len);
```

Even though `buf` being an *"array to 4096 char"* can be converted implicitly to *"pointer to char"*:
Without the `/J` compilation option, Visual-C++'s `char` is [signed by default](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc953fe1%28v=VS.71%29.aspx) -> `signed char`.
For two types A and B, C++ performs a conversion from "pointer to A" to "pointer to B" only if B is a base class of A (§4.10 conv.ptr).
Since this isn't the case for `unsigned char` and `signed char`, the conversion is not implicit (not in a standard conversion sequence, §4 conv).

You can, though, cast it explicitly using a `reinterpret_cast`:

```
signed char as[4096];
int const len = sizeof(as)/sizeof(as[0]);
unsigned char* pu = reinterpret_cast < unsigned char* > (as);
f1(pu, len);
```

**Is this the best way to pass the array?**
There's a subtlety: If the function is explicitly specialized for `unsigned char`, it could "misunderstand" the content of a passed `signed char` buffer. Additionally, if `f1` changes the array, the one interpreting the `signed char` buffer could conflict with what `f1` did (as `f1` worked on an array of `unsigned char`).
But if you know what `f1` does and how the buffer is interpreted, you can do this cast.

**What's the point? Why isn't an implicit or `static_cast` allowed here?**
There could be a special case for conversions between pointers to `signed` and `unsigned` types (having the same object representation), but I didn't find one. Basically, one wants to avoid casts like:

```
short s = 42;
long* pl = &s;
*pl = 4000; // possibly stack corruption

long l = 4200;
short* ps = &l;
*ps = 42;
//- value of l dependent e.g. on endianess
```

---

**Background/Standard**
I've been a bit (or more) curious as to what the `reinterpret_cast` actually does, so the rest here is detail about what the Standard says about it.
Effectively, the `reinterpret_cast` is resolved to (§5.2.10/7 expr.reinterpret.cast):

```
unsigned char* pu = static_cast < unsigned char* > ( static_cast < void* > (as) );
```

Let's go into details.

Inner `static_cast < void* > (as)`:
`static_cast` is allowed to do "array-to-pointer" conversions (§5.2.9/8 expr.static.cast) and a standard conversion sequence (§5.2.9/4, compare §4/3 conv).
The standard conversion sequence allows a conversion from *"pointer to A"* to *"pointer to void"*. It's guaranteed to point at the start of the memory location of the operand. This is fine, as an array consists of an contiguously allocated set of its elements (§8.3.4 dcl.array).

Outer `static_cast < unsigned char* >`:
This is the inverse of a standard conversion - namely, *"pointer to unsigned char"* to *"pointer to void"* (§5.2.9/7 + 13). It's not defined what the result is (unspecified) as we convert from *"pointer to signed char"* via a *"pointer to void"* to *"pointer to unsigned char"*. Note `char` and `unsigned char` are distinct types (§3.9.1/1 basic.fundamental). But it should be ok on any sane machine/implementation as `signed char` and `unsigned char` have the same object representation.

Answer (score 1):

Can you change the declaration of your buffer to the expected type? If so I would recommend:

```
const unsigned int BUFFER_SIZE = 4096;
unsigned char buf[BUFFER_SIZE];
string result = f1(buf, BUFFER_SIZE);
```

If you don't have control over that variable you might do

```
string result = f1(reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(buf), sizeof(buf)/sizeof(buf[0]));
```

Comment: static_cast<unsigned char*>(buf) won't work, reinterpret_cast must be used here

Answer (score 0):

Surprisingly `f1((unsigned char*)buf, len);` will do the trick.